# Why when "fluxions" are zero can equation be considered linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Reading an article form the 40's, there is a passage like this:

[image: fluxions]

Why can the equations be considered linear? (I assume "fluxions" are the derivatives.)

P.S.: Article is "Effects of Controls on Stability, Ashby, 1945", p. 7 in Mechanisms of Intelligence, full [PDF here](http://pespmc1.vub.ac.be/books/Ashby-Mechanisms_of_intelligence.pdf).

Comment: What article is this?

Comment: Effects of Controls on Stability, p. 7 in Mechanisms of Intelligence, full pdf here: http://pespmc1.vub.ac.be/books/Ashby-Mechanisms_of_intelligence.pdf

Comment: Briefly, Taylor-expand the $f_{i}$ and discard terms of degree $2$ and higher.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks, but why discard them?

Comment: Because they are small. "Near the equilibrium" means very small perturbations, which are so much smaller in second or higher degree.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you. I see, so "near the equilibrium" mean small perturbations, because *at* the point of equilibrium the difference is exactly zero (from state to state). But *near* such a point, they are slight.

Answer (score 1):

Fluxions are the old word for derivatives. The article is saying that a nonlinear set of equations can be linearized near an equilibrium--which is when derivatives are zero. In your case equilibria occur exactly at the simultaneous roots of the $f_i$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Let $F$ be a sufficiently smooth (real- or vector-valued) function of one or more real variables. The overarching principle is, the qualitative behavior of $F$ at a point $p$ is dominated by the value $F(p)$; if this value vanishes, the behavior is dominated by the first-degree approximation $DF(p)(x - p)$; if the first-degree approximation is zero, the behavior is dominated by the second-order terms $\frac{1}{2!} D^{2}F(p)(x - p)^{2}$ in the Taylor expansion, etc.

Familiar applications abound in calculus:

- A local extremum of a function can only occur at a critical point: If $F$ is a (continuously-differentiable) real-valued function of one variable and $F'(p) \neq 0$, then $F$ is locally monotone near $p$.

  In case it helps, if $F$ is real-valued and twice continuously-differentiable, then for $x$ sufficiently close to $p$,
  $$
    f(x) = f(p) + f'(p)(x - p) + \tfrac{1}{2!}f''(p)(x - p)^{2} + o(x - p)^{2}.
    $$
  If $f(p) = 0$, this rearranges to
  $$
    f(x) = (x - p)\bigl[f'(p) + \tfrac{1}{2!}f''(p)(x - p) + o(x - p)\bigr],
    $$
  which is approximately linear, since the terms in square brackets are approximately $f'(p)$ for $x \approx p$.
- If $DF(p) = 0$ and $D^{2}F(p)$ is positive-definite, then $p$ is a local minimum of $F$. If instead $D^{2}F(p)$ is negative-definite, then $p$ is a local maximum of $F$.

Now for your actual question: Suppose $F$ is an $\Reals^{n}$-valued function on an open neighborhood of $p$ in $\Reals^{n}$, and you want to investigate the qualitative behavior of the first-order differential equation
$$
x'(t) = F(x(t))
\tag{*}
$$
near $p$.

If $F(p) \neq 0$, then the constant term dominates, and the solutions of (*) are approximately
$$
x(t) \approx x(0) + tF(p).
$$

If $F(p) = 0$ but the matrix $A = DF(p)$ is non-singular (invertible), then (in senses that can be quantified if necessary) the system (*) is approximately $x' = Ax$, and the solutions are approximately
$$
x(t) \approx \exp(tA) x(0).
$$
Particularly, if the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of $A = DF(p)$ are known (or generally, its [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) is known), then the [local qualitative behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Linear_differential_equation_systems) of the original system can be read off.

Presumably that's the paper's rationale for linear approximation.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. The math is a bit too advanced for me. (For example, what is DF? Is that determinant?)

Comment: $DF$ is the first derivative, the $m \times n$ Jacobian matrix if $F$ is an $\mathbf{R}^{m}$-valued function of $n$ variables; $D^{2}F$ is the second derivative, the Hessian of $F$. If that doesn't help, could you please say a bit more about your mathematical background? :)

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, just took calculus and algebra in university. I guess I was looking for more so intuitive explanation than a technical one. (e.g. I just want to understand why he made that claim? why not keep it as a function of all powers of x, but resort to reducing it to linear form? I guess for ease of analysis?)

Comment: Intuitively, $x^{2}$ is very small compared to $x$ when $x$ is small, so neglecting everything but first-order terms is a reasonably good approximation. As you say, a differential equation $x'(t) = F(x(t))$ is easier to analyze if $F$ is linear than if $F$ is non-linear, yet the qualitative behavior is "essentially the same".

Comment: and $x$ is small because we are near the point of equilibrium. I see!